# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.Application.getProperties()Ljava/util/Map in jersy rest-rx 2.x

Tags: java, rest, web-services

I am trying to build a rest service using jersy implementation for jax-rs- 2.x . I am using weblogic server i am getting the below exception.

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.Application.getProperties()Ljava/util/Map;
Message icon - Error javax.ws.rs.core.Application.getProperties()Ljava/util/Map;

Note: i am not using maven repository for jars.  Manually added all required jars.
See the attachment of my jars.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZsuUM.png)

I searched lot, and tried different alternatives but no luck. Also tried by adding jhades, when i run jhades to know the conflicting jars it displayed

> > jHades - scanning classpath for overlapping jars:

No results found.

Any help to get rid of this problem?

Comment: I too have the same issue.. Did you find any solution for this?